# Should I worry about "Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced"?

Tags: debian, proxmox, numa

I have a NUMA system with two Xeon E5-2680 v3's. System is running Debian 11.5 (Proxmox VE 7.3-3). When making sure that NUMA was enabled I noticed this in my `dmesg`:

```
root@(host):~# dmesg | grep -i numa
[    0.012447] NUMA: Initialized distance table, cnt=2
[    0.837552] mempolicy: Enabling automatic NUMA balancing. Configure with numa_balancing= or the kernel.numa_balancing sysctl
[    1.285994] pci_bus 0000:ff: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
[    1.291909] pci_bus 0000:7f: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
[    1.317653] pci_bus 0000:00: on NUMA node 0
[    1.323740] pci_bus 0000:80: on NUMA node 1
```

Upon seing this, I looked at `lspci` and saw this:

```
root@NAS:~# lspci | grep '^ff\|^7f'
7f:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
7f:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
7f:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
7f:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
7f:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
7f:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
7f:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU (rev 02)
7f:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU (rev 02)
ff:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
ff:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
ff:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
ff:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
ff:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU (rev 02)
ff:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU (rev 02)
```

So it looks to me like those two PCI devices are internal to each CPU. Is this something I should be concerned about/are there some drivers/modules I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, that is two of the internal PCI busses... And they may be bridging the cores???

As it isn't a device you are going to be passing through, I wouldn't worry about it.